# App crashes with storage exception,while dealing with images in firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase-storage

Following is my piece of code.
this code runs in a loop for many images and images are shown( the whole code runs as expected).
and suddenly app crashes with this error.

> Error:: StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
>                                                        Object does not exist at location.
>                                                         Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404

And no line of my code is directed for the cause of the error.

```
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("storage_location");
StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child("imgPath");
pathReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        holder.ivIcon2.setImageUrl(uri.toString(), MySingleton.getInstance(activity).getImageLoader());


    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.d("tag", e.toString());
    }
});
```

Don't have any idea of the origin of the issue.

**Deleting and reuploading all the images in Storage solve the problem for the time.**